# Component level onChange event?

Tags: reactjs

I have an options page comonent. This component is composed of row. Each row is a setting. That setting is either a select, check, radio, or custom element. This component is updated in two ways:

1. AJAX tells it to update with setState - this setState I classify not as component onChange but JUST component update
2. User manipulates a row, triggering the select/radio/check onChange to trigger, the onChange triggers a setState on the top most component - this setState I classify as component onChange

When #2 happens, meaning the user manipulated component, I want the onChange on the top most component to fire. Is there an event like this? I cant seem to find it in component life cycle.

Reason why I cannot use `componentDidUpdate`, is because when user triggers onChange of row, I need to make a request to server with the new info. If AJAX tells the compoent to update, onComponentDidUpdate will trigger, but I don't need to make an AJAX request.

Comment: Donn't know what exactly you want. Cann't that pass `onChange` from parent component to the rows with props solve your problems? What `the onChange on the top most component to fire` means please? do you mean event delegation?

Comment: Thanks @ZhangChao for quick reply. Basically, I want to know if the `componentDidUpdate` that triggered on the top most component, is due to user manipulated setState, or from AJAX setState.

Comment: When user manipulation cause `onChange`, you want trigger `setState` and then make a request in `componentDidUpdate`,  am I right? Why don't you make this request in `onChange`, and trigger `setState` when get response of this request? I think this is a more common way to do such things, and you don't have to make a distinction between ajax way and user way in `componentDidUpdate`.

Comment: I was hesitant to use onChange, because what if it triggered when in fact nothing changed. But I think react makes onChange work differently, in that it does not trigger unless it was really changed, is this true? Thanks @ZhangChao !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that by passing a callback from Top Component on its Child component Property. The callback then will be invoked by Child component onChange event by using this.props.callbackName(). For example

TopComponent.js

```
 // import react (i'm using es2015)
 // but the concept is the same whether you use it or not

 import React, {Component} from 'react'

 class TopComponent extends Component {

     // the callback
     onChildComponentChange(){
       doAjax().then(function(data){
         this.setState({foo: data})
       })

     }

     render(){
         return (<ChildComponent onPropertyChange={this.onChildComponentChange}) />
     }
 }
```

ChildComponent.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

class ChildComponent extends Component {

  onChangeHandler(){
    // from this handler we call the top component callback
    this.props.onPropertyChange(data) // the name of props we pass from top component
  }
  render(){
    return (<RowComponent onClick={this.onChangeHandler}/>)
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah this is just good thinking, thank you very much! I learn some es2015 from this post too, thank you!

Comment: is it possible to name the callback function (the one you're naming `onPropertyChange`) `onChange`? I would like to, in order to keep consistency, but, would I be overriding something important? thanks

Comment: what if we want to pass a event as a parameter in call back so we could access value in event.target.value ?